# how can I make my python selenium project work on heroku

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, web-scraping

So I have this selenium project that works perfectly locally , it's just a script that scrapes data from a website  . I managed to successfully deploy the script into heroku but when I try to activate it it shows me these errors .

it gives an error that it is failing to find some of the xpath elements that it's supposed to scrape from the website.
this is the error that it's displaying

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='_cs_button _cs_button--sm _cs_button--positive _cs_m-down--none']"}
(Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.77)

after that I decided to print the source of the website before the code tried to find the elements, because I thought maybe the elements just weren't there so it couldn't find them and it turns out that the js that it recieves from the website doesn't get activated and so the html isn't recieved after .

I pretty much can't understand why when activated on heroku the script doesn't activate the js recieved from the website

Can someone please help me with this

Comment: It should just be a warning?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the Python version you are using in the Heroku instance is >3.8, while the local version is not.

In Python 3.8 or above, it will now raise syntax warning when using `is` to compare integers or string literals. Since the library is trying to compare `setting` to an empty string, it will raise such an error. The script `firefox_profile.py` will be called is because selenium will check the browser version that your script uses, which should not cause an issue for your scripts as this is only an *warning* instead of an *exception*.

To fix this, you may downgrade the Python version in your Heroku instance, or submit a PR in the selenium repository.

---

Update:

As I just checked the official repository, the issue should be fixed in the latest version, you can find the commit [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/0e0194b0e52a34e7df4b841f1ed74506beea5c3e#diff-323be8fb876362e1b98205768bcd1e386d4607db6a5164932f7b34e091a22cc1). You can update to the latest version of the library to fix it.