# No output from web scraping script deployed on Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, heroku, web-scraping

I am scraping an eCommerce site for product listing. if I work on Jupyter notebook, I get all links to the 50 items that come on that page. From there I go to each page to get the image, name, description, and price of that particular product. There I had given the full path to chrome driver. When I deployed it on Heroku the script doesn't work and returns me the empty list. I have added the three build packs(python, chrome, and chrome driver) and also set the config vars in the Heroku settings.

```
import selenium
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
op=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.binary_location=os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
op.add_argument("--headless")
op.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
op.add_argument("--disable-dev-sh-usage")
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"),options=op)
search = input ("Enter product :")
driver.get('https://www.myntra.com/{}'.format(search))
listOfLinks=[]
productInfoList=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('product-base')
for product in productInfoList:
    ppp1=product.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
    listOfLinks.append(ppp1.get_property('href'))
allDetails=[]
print(listOfLinks)
for i in listOfLinks:
    driver.get(i)
    try:
        check=driver.find_element_by_class_name('pdp-pdp-container')
        element=driver.find_element_by_class_name('image-grid-image')
        str=element.value_of_css_property('background-image')
        list=str.split('"')
        img=list[1]
        product_name=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mountRoot"]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/h1[1]').text
        product_desc=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mountRoot"]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/h1[2]').text
        product_price=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mountRoot"]/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/p[1]/span[1]/strong').text
        temp={
        'Image':img,
        'Product':product_name,
        'Details':product_desc,
        'Price':product_price,
        'Link':i}
        allDetails.append(temp)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("error")
        continue
df=pd.DataFrame(allDetails)
jd=df.to_json()
print(jd)
```

Comment: Are there any errors/logs?

Comment: C:\Users\chink\Desktop\fashion-web-scraper>heroku run python app.py
Running python app.py on ⬢ fashion-web-scraper... up, run.6982 (Free)
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py:208: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if setting is None or setting is '':
Enter product :shirts
[]
{}

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67787707/how-can-i-make-my-python-selenium-project-work-on-heroku). It looks like it may have to do with the python version you are using locally vs 3.9 in heroku. Guessing you are using < 3.8 locally?

Comment: Tried downscaling to 3.7 to skip that warning but the app doesn't get pushed
remote: -----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
remote:  !     Requested runtime (python-3.7) is not available for this stack (heroku-20).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: To https://git.heroku.com/fashion-web-scraper.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fashion-web-scraper.git'

Comment: version of python in my pc

C:\Users\chink>python -V
Python 3.9.5